# Efficient computation of the set of surjective functions

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, tuples, combinatorics

A function `f : X -> Y` is surjective when every element of `Y` has at least one preimage in `X`. When `X = {0,...,m-1}` and `Y = {0,...,n-1}` are two finite sets, then `f` corresponds to an `m`-tuple of numbers `< n`, and it is surjective precisely when every number `< n` appears at least once. (When we require that every number appears *exactly* once, we have `n=m` and are talking about *permutations*.)

I would like to know an efficient algorithm for computing the set of all surjective tuples for two given numbers `n` and `m`. The *number* of these tuples can be computed very efficiently with the inclusion-exclusion principle (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3116932)), but I don't think that this is useful here (since we would first compute *all tuples* and then remove the non-surjective ones step by step, and I assume that the computation of *all tuples* will take longer*.). A different approach goes as follows:

Consider for example the tuple

`(1,6,4,2,1,6,0,2,5,1,3,2,3)`

in which every number < 7 appears at least once. Look at the largest
number and erase it:

`(1,*,4,2,1,*,0,2,5,1,3,2,3)`

It appears in the indices 1 and 5, so this corresponds to the set `{1,5}`, a subset of the indices.
The rest corresponds to the tuple

`(1,4,2,1,0,2,5,1,3,2,3)`

with the property that every number < 6 appears at least once.

We see that the surjective `m`-tuples of numbers `< n` correspond to the pairs `(T,a)`, where `T` is a non-empty subset of `{0,...,m-1}` and `a` is a surjective `(m-k)`-tuple of numbers `< n-1`, where `T` has `k` elements.

This leads to the following recursive implementation (written in Python):

```
import itertools


def surjective_tuples(m: int, n: int) -> set[tuple]:
    """Set of all m-tuples of numbers < n where every number < n appears at least once.

    Arguments:
        m: length of the tuple
        n: number of distinct values
    """
    if n == 0:
        return set() if m > 0 else {()}
    if n > m:
        return set()
    result = set()
    for k in range(1, m + 1):
        smaller_tuples = surjective_tuples(m - k, n - 1)
        subsets = itertools.combinations(range(m), k)
        for subset in subsets:
            for smaller_tuple in smaller_tuples:
                my_tuple = []
                count = 0
                for i in range(m):
                    if i in subset:
                        my_tuple.append(n - 1)
                        count += 1
                    else:
                        my_tuple.append(smaller_tuple[i - count])
                result.add(tuple(my_tuple))
    return result
```

I noticed that this is quite slow, though, when the input numbers are large. For example when `(m,n)=(10,6)` the computation takes `32` seconds on my (old) PC, the set has `16435440` elements here. I suspect that there is a faster algorithm.

*In fact, the following implementation is *very slow*.

```
def surjective_tuples_stupid(m: int, n: int) -> list[int]:
    all_tuples = list(itertools.product(*(range(n) for _ in range(m))))
    surjective_tuples = filter(lambda t: all(i in t for i in range(n)), all_tuples)
    return list(surjective_tuples)
```

Comment: How slow is it? And how large are your numbers?

Comment: [Nicer stupid way](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=lZJLTgMxDIYllnMKLxM07YpFNdJwEVSN5uEBQ15KHARnYdMNHIrT4M60tNKIomYTOfH_5bfjj6_wzk_e7XafmcfV5vvmhWzwkYEYI3tvUlEMOELK8Rl7pldsOAeDqUmy06BsBeS4BDftGlb3YCjxgwTbqgBZrTEHDdTTnfplr0P0Q-5Z3arYukdUTsPoIzTCgvnEalkTZ2FBcCMZYSnT2m5ogav9Y4r2ap5AdAI5rcszLzMzIufoZlcLvr5cetNlbhz1eG0PluUfHZZiKGDLtf235IQnmV5TSrmTo-srtGJbqJsS7gp8C3It0d-_Ldm6iJiyuZR31ppJEKK0Qh1lNcwP6XnmDqN3HMEf) (faster, too).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just optimized yours a little, mainly by using `insert` to build the tuple. About 5x faster than yours for m=9, n=7.

```
def surjective_tuples(m: int, n: int) -> list[tuple]:
    """List of all m-tuples of numbers < n where every number < n appears at least once.

    Arguments:
        m: length of the tuple
        n: number of distinct values
    """
    if not n:
        return [] if m else [()]
    if n > m:
        return []
    n -= 1
    result = []
    for k in range(1, m - n + 1):
        smaller_tuples = surjective_tuples(m - k, n)
        subsets = itertools.combinations(range(m), k)
        for subset in subsets:
            for smaller_tuple in smaller_tuples:
                my_tuple = [*smaller_tuple]
                for i in subset:
                    my_tuple.insert(i, n)
                result.append(tuple(my_tuple))
    return result
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! On my PC it is about 3x faster. I understand why `.insert` is better here, but I was wondering why (and I tested this) using sets makes the function slower. (By the way, in your docstring we need to update Set->List.) Apart from the fact that the problem comes from mathematics where we are indeed interested in a *set*, I thought that sets are more efficient than lists because they are implemented as hash tables. But maybe this is only true when we already have a set, not when we build it up because Python needs to check if newly added elements are actually new. Is this correct?

Comment: And another question: I didn't try it, because it would make the code unreadable, but would it be more performant to use iterated list comprehensions and `functools.reduce` and perhaps also `map` to convert these four for-loops into one line?

Comment: @ScriptRaccoon Ok I changed the docstring. I had left it since there are no duplicates, so in that sense it's still a set (just not a `set`). Sets are fast at *membership checks*, but we don't need any (unless you do some *afterwards*, i.e., with the code that calls the function and then does something with the results) since we don't produce duplicate tuples anyway. But the support for those faster membership checks comes at the price of making other operations slower. Yes, adding to a set is slower than appending to a list because the set checks whether the new element is actually new.

Comment: @ScriptRaccoon And about the list comprehension: I had considered it, but I don't think it would be faster. Creating each tuple is probably much more costly than putting it into the output, so the time saved by a  comprehension would be relatively small compared to that. And my way to create each tuple doesn't really translate to a comprehension or reduce/map, so that would likely cost extra time, more than it saves.

Comment: Alright. Thank you for the additional explanation 

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to improve few %s of performance using `sympy`s [`multiset_permutations`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/iterables.html#sympy.utilities.iterables.multiset_permutations):

```py
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

from sympy.utilities.iterables import multiset_permutations


def get_combs(s, n):
    for c in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, s), n):
        if sum(c) == s:
            yield c

def surjective_tuples_new(s, n):
    for c in get_combs(s, n):
        for p in multiset_permutations(c):
            out = []

            for i, n in enumerate(p):
                out.extend(i for _ in range(n))

            yield from multiset_permutations(out)
```

---

Benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit

assert sorted(surjective_tuples_new(10, 8)) == list(
    map(list, sorted(surjective_tuples(10, 8)))
)

t1 = timeit("surjective_tuples(10, 8)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("list(surjective_tuples_new(10, 8))", number=1, globals=globals())
t3 = timeit("surjective_tuples_kelly(10, 8)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700x, Python 3.11):

```
27.863450561184436
22.92276939912699
9.207325214054435
```

EDIT: Added @kelly's answer to the benchmark.

Comment: Can you time mine as well? I don't have enough memory for 10,8.

Comment: @KellyBundy Added your answer to the benchmark. Seems fast :)

Comment: Maybe yours would become faster than mine at larger numbers. For 8,6 mine seems about 5 times faster, for 9,7 mine seems about 4 times faster, and for 10,8 it already seems only about 2.5 times faster.